# Datastax OpsCenter upgrade from 6.0.3 to 6.0.5: migration of lcm.db

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

I upgraded OpsCenter from 6.0.3 to 6.0.5.  Is there a way to migrate the LCM data?  Is it as simple as copying the file lcm.db?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpsCenter developer here. 6.0.3 to 6.0.5 is a safe upgrade to do "in-place". So if it's a package you can just 'yum upgrade' or 'apt-get upgrade'.

If you do want to backup/restore your settings for whatever reason, the best docs to look at are our high-availability docs (HA failover is basically a backup/restore): https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/opsc/configure/enableFailover.html. The upgrade docs may also be useful https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/opscenter/upgdOpsc.html.

The TLDR for LCM (off the top of my head) is:

- lcm.db
- The 'ssl' directory if you have node-to-node or client-to-node enabled (this is where the LCM certificate authority is, and if you fail to restore this you'll have trouble adding nodes later when you can't issue compatible certs for them).
- The db crypto key in the 'keys' directory (if you fail to restore this you'll have trouble accessing encryted database fields like the password or ssh-private-key of your ssh-credentials).

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I finally have 6.0.5 up and running.