# Datastax OpsCenter backup fails after upgrade to 6.0.5

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

Backup does not work after upgrading from 6.0.3 to 6.0.5, with the following error.  The agents are healthy according to the agents tab.  Works again after rolling back to 6.0.3.  Any help is much appreciated.

`2016-11-20 16:50:15,952 [opscenterd]  WARN: Marking request 'Backup' (adc0b98e-0533-497d-8e3b-5316834ed9b1) a\
s failed: Backup of keyspaces [sponte] failed for the following destinations: snapshot (MainThread)
2016-11-20 16:50:15,952 [sponte] ERROR: Backup of keyspaces [sponte] failed: Backup of keyspaces [sponte] fai\
led for the following destinations: snapshot (MainThread)
2016-11-20 16:50:15,953 [opscenterd] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred: Backup of keyspaces [sponte] failed:\
 Backup of keyspaces [sponte] failed for the following destinations: snapshot (MainThread)
2016-11-20 16:50:16,159 [sponte]  INFO: agent_config items: {'cassandra_user': 'cassandra', 'jmx_pass': '****\
*', 'metrics_ignored_keyspaces': 'system, system_traces, system_auth, system_distributed, dse_auth, OpsCenter\
', 'cassandra_log_location': '/var/log/cassandra', 'rollups60_ttl': 604800, 'cassandra_install_location': '',\
 'cassandra_pass': '*****', 'monitored_cassandra_port': 9042, 'monitored_thrift_port': 9160, 'rollups86400_tt\
l': 0, 'jmx_user': '', 'jmx_port': 7199, 'storage_keyspace': 'OpsCenter', 'jmx_operations_pool_size': 4, 'met\
rics_ignored_solr_cores': '', 'rollups300_ttl': 2419200, 'use_ssl': False, 'metrics_ignored_column_families':\
 '', 'restore_req_update_period': 1, 'rollups7200_ttl': 31536000, 'api_port': '61621', 'thrift_port': 9160, '\
monitored_cassandra_user': 'cassandra', 'max_pending_repairs': 5, 'cassandra_port': 9042, 'monitored_cassandr\
a_pass': '*****', 'ec2_metadata_api_host': '169.254.169.254', 'backup_staging_dir': '', 'metrics_enabled': Tr\
ue} (MainThread)
2016-11-20 16:50:16,193 [opscenterd] ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred: Resource not found.
  File "/sponte/opscenter-6.0.5/lib/py/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1124, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)`

File "build/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 1446, in RequestStatusController
 (MainThread)

Comment: What did you do to upgrade the first time?  What docs did you follow?

Comment: I just installed 6.0.5 and the agents.  What I did not do was to copy the files over from the 6.0.3 installation as described in the upgrade doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup works after redoing OpsCenter upgrade using instruction from 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/opscenter/upgdOpsc.html

Got the answer from here

[Datastax OpsCenter upgrade from 6.0.3 to 6.0.5: migration of lcm.db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698825/datastax-opscenter-upgrade-from-6-0-3-to-6-0-5-migration-of-lcm-db)